# Do updates to page layouts reflect on current pages?

Tags: publishing, page-layout

I am working on a 2010 Publishing site.  We have a bunch of pages tha are based off of a layout that controls news stories.  We have made the change in the layout which is just adding some additional text and font color to a page content field.  However, pages that were created off this layout previously, are not being updated.  New pages created off layout are fine. I was under impression this was the luxury of layouts that pages I built off a layout that is changed will also update.  Not just new pages.  Can someone clarify for me?

Answer (score 3):

Pages based on the page layout should get updated when you change the page layout.

A couple of reasons why this might not work are:

1) You are trying to change the page layout in the SharePoint root directory (e.g. by deploying a solution package) but the layout has been customized in SharePoint Designer. In this case changing the page layout on the file system will have no effect. You will need to revert the page layout to the template in SharePoint Designer or through the UI.

2) The page is being cached, and so the changes are not being seen. For example if you have page output caching it may take a while to see the effects, depending on the cache settings. You can do an iisreset to make sure (assuming you are not on a production server). It could also be cached in the browser or on a proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

Your changes to the layout page will have to be published and approved if you have approvals turned on. This also holds for any CSS files that you might have changed.

Answer (score 1):

What I've observed is that the Pages that have been published will not reflect changes to 'Page layout' after the page was published.

Sometimes, editing the inheriting pages in SPD will break their connection with the Page Layout. As a result, they will stop reflecting changes in page layout.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your page that was not updated and re-select your page layout. This should force it to update.

I'm having the same issue here and the only solution I found was it. Still wondering now how i'm going to do it in the other thousands of page which uses this page-layout (updating via powershell did not worked, only worked by manually doing it)